# How to detect duplicate in foreach DB query

Tags: php, mysql, foreach, duplicates

I have a function getRows() that can be run in a foreach loop. It gives me all the rows returned from a MySQL query. The names are stored as `first.last`, and I'm getting just the first name. The problem is there are duplicate names, so I need to do something with them if they are the same (I was thinking of getting a substring of the last name).

Given my function, how can I check for dupes and perform another action?

**Function getRows()**

```
public function getRows($query, $params = []) {
    try {
        $stmt = $this->db_data->prepare($query);
        $stmt->execute($params);
        return $stmt->fetchAll();
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        throw new Exception($e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

**The foreach**

```
<?php

foreach($division_result = $db->getRows('SELECT * FROM users WHERE division=? ORDER BY username', ['AWM']) as $division) {
    $username = $division['username'];
    $short_list_name = substr($username, 0, strpos($username, '.'));
    echo $short_list_name . '<br>';
}
?>
```

**The result**

```
alicia
amy
angel
ashley
caitlin
cassie
cory
courtney
debbie
gabby
jamie
kamron
kelly
mallory
oliver
rhonda
tim <-- THIS ONE
tim <-- AND THIS ONE
tommy
travis
```

I can run

```
 mysql> SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(username, '.', 1) FROM users WHERE division='AWM' GROUP BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(username, '.', 1) HAVING count(*) > 1;
```

from terminal, which produces:

```
+-----------------------------------+
| SUBSTRING_INDEX(username, '.', 1) |
+-----------------------------------+
| tim                               |
+-----------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

**Edit**
But I don't know how I would incorporate that into my current foreach since I need both names. I just need to detect them and do something different with the strings.

Comment: `array_unique`? `DISCTINCT` ? `in_array`?

Comment: Use MySQL's [`DISTINCT`](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-distinct.aspx) keyword: `SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(DISTINCT username, '.', 1) `

Comment: Maybe I worded it wrong. I know how to get distinct values, but I need both of them to show. I just need to detect them and do something with those strings.

Comment: you could run a `if(condition) >1`

Comment: You can add a short names to array and compare any new short name with the existing names in the array. But the better way is change the db structure by separate the first and last name to a different columns, I think.

Comment: @toor Thank you for your suggestion, but I can't change the schema. It is how everyone logs in to our other systems (first.last).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store list of names in array and check exist a name in it

```
$names = [];
foreach($division_result = $db->getRows('SELECT * FROM users WHERE division=? ORDER BY username', ['AWM']) as $division) {
    $username = $division['username'];
    $short_list_name = substr($username, 0, strpos($username, '.'));
    if (in_array($short_list_name, $names)) {
        // another action
    } else {
        $names[] = $short_list_name;
        echo $short_list_name . '<br>';
    }

}
```

?>

Comment: I moved the last echo statement into the else block. That does exactly what I had in mind. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to add the data in your query. If used on a light DB, you could rewrite your request like so :

```
SELECT * 
FROM users join 
     (SELECT username,COUNT(*) as dupes FROM users GROUP BY username) as foo using(username) 
WHERE division=? 
ORDER BY username
```

Quite heavy, and may not work on all DB. But more direct, after that you juste need to check `dupes`>1.